# SeleniumLibrary instalation problem (robot framework)

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

Trying to instrall SeleniumLibrary into RED - Robot framework.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
```

seem to not work. As i know in red.xml i must add the library but in the "...Lib/site-packages" there is no folder for SeleniumLibrary where I can select the _*init*.py. Only robotframework_seleniumlibrary-5.0.0b2.dev1-py3.9.egg file

Comment: Source: C:\Users\kalapcievv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\robotframework_seleniumlibrary-4.5.0-py3.9.egg\SeleniumLibrary\__init__.py seems does not exists

Comment: What does "not to work" mean? Why do you think it's not working?